# How can I make image opaque to some level?

Tags: android, image

I would like to know if I can make an image opaque if set in image view or set as background of relative layout.

How can I make image opaque using image view or relative layout for setting the image dynamically or Is there any other option to set image and its opacity dynamically?

I also want the same image to rotate in both directions and also can zoomin and zoomout to anylevel.

Thanks in advance

Comment: One way I am aware of is to do image pre-processing (using Bitmap functions for that) and then dinamically (from code) set it as background for Relative Layout or src for ImageView. But I guess it is not what you want. You would like to do that from control itself, but I do not see any property for that except maybe Style.

Comment: @Zelimir - can you explain with example that you know

Comment: I have added my answer. It describes principle, so you can easily adapt it to your needs.

Comment: If you want to make it opaque (transparent) to some level, change aplha value 128 from code sample to some other number between 0-255.

Comment: @Zelimir - I just want to ask one thing that can we rotate the image ontouch of image as the movement fingures happens to any degree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working and tested code below.

```
private void applyTransformToImageView(int code)
{
    Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.image2);
    Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult); 

    switch (code)
    {
        case CHANGE_TRANSPARENCY:
        {
            Paint alphaPaint = new Paint();
            alphaPaint.setAlpha(128);
            tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, alphaPaint);               
        }
        break;

        case ROTATE:
        {
            tempCanvas.rotate(90, bmpOriginal.getWidth()/2, bmpOriginal.getHeight()/2);
            tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, null);
        }
        break;

        case ZOOM_IN:
        {               
            Rect zoomRegion = new Rect();
            zoomRegion.left = 0;
            zoomRegion.top = 0;
            zoomRegion.right = bmpOriginal.getWidth()/2;
            zoomRegion.bottom = bmpOriginal.getHeight()/2;

            Rect display = new Rect();
            display.left = 0;
            display.top = 0;
            display.right = bmpOriginal.getWidth();
            display.bottom = bmpOriginal.getHeight();

            tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, zoomRegion, display, null);
        }
        break;

        default:
    }

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmResult);            
}
```

- sets alpha to semi-transparent - value 128
- rotates around original image center for 90 degrees
- zoom into top left quadrant of the original image