# Is it possible to use a drawable with different rotations in an xml layout?

Tags: android

I am trying to display a table of 4 players. I have a table drawable and a chair drawable.
I want to use chair drawable four times around the table with different orientations. Is it possible?

I don't want to use four different drawables (chair_north, chair_east, chair_south, chair_west)  to draw the chairs around the table. This will increase the size of the application.

EDIT: Can I do this with just resources xml files? (without any java code)

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763103/rotating-a-drawable-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For API 11 and up you can use something like

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewArrowUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:rotation="-90" />
```

to rotate the view -90 degrees. Depending on what you have in your drawable you can rotate the view to the other 3 orientations.