# Rotate a drawable before playing its frame animation

Tags: android

I have an animationDrawable that has a list of frames (one by one) to display them as an animation.

The problem is that I want that drawable to be rotated 45 degree. Is there a way to rotate it before so the animation plays on a diagonal?

Thank you

Here is a XML animation

```
<animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/imag1" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/imag2" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/imag3" android:duration="150" />
 </animation-list>
```

and here is the code

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

//I want to rotate here

AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
frameAnimation.start();
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763103/rotating-a-drawable-in-android

Comment: you want to rotate the drawable?  use RotateDrawable ckass

Comment: Thanks for the link but it talks about bitmapdrawbale. See the code that  I have above, how can I rotate that?

Comment: as i said, use RotateDrawable: http://codeshare.io/wz41j

Comment: @pskink, Thank you but my object is not of type rotatedrawable. It is AnimationDrawable.

Comment: what object? did you see my code? take a look into xml drawable i posted

Comment: Ohhhh I see, you had the animation list inside the rotate one. I guess I can accept it as an answer but I was hoping to rotate it in the code because  I have over 40 xml that  I really hate to change all of them

Comment: so see my link again

Comment: Excellllleeent! .Do you want to post it here so I accept it and others beneift from it

Comment: Also in addition since you have a lot of experience, can you check the last question I posted? I reaaaaaally hope you can help out with this as it is becoming a show stopper in my project :(